# Jenkins: Is there a way to list "labels" in a dropdown, to select one as a parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking to have all of the defined node labels as a dropdown, so that I can select one to pass to the build as a parameter. Then in the build I'd loop through all the hosts in that label.

Comment: What "labels" exactly do you mean? Are you talking about labels in Github? Or do you mean a pre-defined list of labels?

Comment: Node / slaves labels?

Comment: Yes, node labels. I'm aware of the NodeLabel plugin, but I don't want to manually specify the label, I want to be able to select from a list of existing labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the answer I finally worked out

Use "Extensible choice parameter" as the parameter (Install plugin if needed)
Choice Provider : "System Groovy Choice Parameter"
Do not run in Sandbox

And here's the Groovy code

```
import jenkins.model.*
def labelAndNodeList = []
for (label in Jenkins.getInstance().getLabels()) {
   labelAndNodeList.add(label)
}
return labelAndNodeList
```

And to expand on this a bit... Maybe you've called your parameter "Label"
and you now want to loop through the nodes that are assigned that label in a pipeline

Here's the pipeline code

```
def label = "${params.Label}"

listOfNodeNames = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes.collect {
  node -> node.getLabelString().contains(label) ? node.name : null
}
listOfNodeNames.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null))

for (node_to_run_on in listOfNodeNames) {
    println "Node: ${node_to_run_on}"
    node ("${node_to_run_on}") {
        stage("Uname on ${node_to_run_on}") {
            sh ("uname -a")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar functionality to what you're looking for is [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin). You can use multi node selection or use labels, but not sure if you can use dropdown for labels (as I understand, dropdown can be used only for nodes).

Comment: Thanks, not really what I'm looking for though. I'm looking for a list of existing labels, seems like with that plugin you pretty much need to know what label you're looking to act upon, and manually enter it.

Comment: Yes, but you can try to use multi node selection as a workaround. Seems to be that there are no such plugins to use dropdown list for labels.